# Facebook SDK 4 for PHP - no login grab some events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I try to use the Facebook SDK 4 for PHP,

but there is one thing that i don't understand : use it with an app access token!

i tried different tokens to initialize FaceBookSession, but i don't understand how it works... :/

with this sample code for example :

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  '/480602392011337/events?fields=id,end_time,description,is_date_only,location,name,start_time&since='.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 year')).'&until='.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year')).'&limit=500',
  //'/480602392011337/events',
  'GET'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I don't know how to have a valid access token...

with this command :  `$session = new FacebookSession( 'xxxxxxxxx' ); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution (thx Google), simply use `FacebookSession::newAppSession();`

```
// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxx','xxxxxxx');
//  Get the access token for this app
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// make the API call, $datas contains the events for the facebook fan page BDE Polytech Marseille
try {
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/{page-id}/events?fields=id,end_time,description,is_date_only,location,name,start_time&since='.strtotime('-1 year').'&until='.strtotime('+1 year').'&limit=500'
);
$response = $request->execute();

$datas = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

}catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to call for events in the past. I never recieved any events until I realized that there are only past ones....   :(